# P4 -s describe changelist

Tags: perforce

Is there an straight forward command to get only the submitted description of a CL and not the affected files ? I want to get only the one-liner descriptions of a list of change lists and print them all in one file with the CL number.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the "p4 changes" command -- that sounds like it might already have roughly the format you're looking for?

Otherwise, you can get the full description with a command like:

```
p4 -Ztag -F %Description% change -o CHANGENUM
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but this might be what you where looking for:

```
p4 changes -e [changelist#] -r -m 1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: This solution gives only the very first line of the description so it answers the question. However if you want to show the whole description use the solution above given by Samwise: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46229929/2149539

Answer (score 0):

This will give description of all changelists submitted between two dates

`p4 changes -u <username> -l //<depot>/...@2020/01/01,@2021/01/10`